# How to animate and simulate pulling up pants

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I need help in learning what I need to do in order to animate and simulate a character pulling up their pants in a way that also interacts with a soft body mesh. Do i need to parent the hands to the clothing? I'm assuming i'm going to need to do a soft body, collision, and cloth simulation in order to get it all to work. What tutorials or tips should I know to get this to work since i'm new to blender simulations.